# awk - , fixed width columns

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

**AWK: Display variable width columns fields into fixed spaced Column fields Format in Unix.**

```
$ cat temp.txt
QUEUE(XYZ1.REQ.YAM.ALIAS) TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUS) CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH) CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES) PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ4.REPL.YAM) TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYSTER) CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH) CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES) PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.YAM) TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCTER) CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH) CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(NO) PUT(DISABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ8.REPLY.YAM) TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER( ) CLUSQMGR(ABCD) CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES) PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.K.LQ) TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER) CLUSQMGR() CLUSQT(QLOCAL) DEFPSIST(NO) PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.KATHPALIA) TYPE(QREMOTE) CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER) CLUSQMGR(ABCD) CLUSQT(QLOCAL) DEFPSIST(NO) PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(KATHPLAIA.RAMAN) TYPE( ) CLUSTER( ) CLUSQMGR(ABCD) CLUSQT(QLOCAL) DEFPSIST(NO) PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.EQUAL.LQ) TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER) CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH) CLUSQT(QLOCAL) DEFPSIST(YES) PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ9.RAMAN.EQUAL.LQ) TYPE(QL) CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER) CLUSQMGR(ABCD) CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES) PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XX10.REPL.EQUAL.ALIAS) TYPE(QA) CLUSTER(YOURC) CLUSQMGR(ABCD) CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES) PUT(DISABLED)
QUEUE(XX10.KATHPLAIA.EQUAL.LOCAL) TYPE(LOCALQ) CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER) CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH) CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES) PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XX11.RAMAN.EQUAL.LOCAL) TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUS) CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH) CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES) PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XX11.REQ.LOCAL) TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER) CLUSQMGR(ABCD) CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES) PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(RAMAN_KATHPLIA_000_11.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE) TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUS) CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH) CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES) PUT(DISABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.RAMAN.REMOTE.QUEUE) TYPE(QLOCAL) CLUSTER(STER) CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH) CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES) PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE) TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER( ) CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH) CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES) PUT(ENABLED)
```

**Expected: A neat column display**

This can be achieved by "column" command:

```
$ cat temp.txt | column -t
QUEUE(XYZ1.REQ.YAM.ALIAS)                            TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUS)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)              DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ4.REPL.YAM)                                 TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYSTER)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS)              DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.YAM)                                  TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCTER)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)              DEFPSIST(NO)    PUT(DISABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ8.REPLY.YAM)                                TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(            )                           CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.K.LQ)                                 TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR()                  CLUSQT(QLOCAL)              DEFPSIST(NO)    PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.KATHPALIA)                            TYPE(QREMOTE)   CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QLOCAL)              DEFPSIST(NO)    PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(KATHPLAIA.RAMAN)                               TYPE(           )                   CLUSTER(                    )                           CLUSQMGR(ABCD)  CLUSQT(QLOCAL)  DEFPSIST(NO)  PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.EQUAL.LQ)                             TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QLOCAL)              DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ9.RAMAN.EQUAL.LQ)                           TYPE(QL)        CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS)              DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XX10.REPL.EQUAL.ALIAS)                         TYPE(QA)        CLUSTER(YOURC)      CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS)              DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(DISABLED)
QUEUE(XX10.KATHPLAIA.EQUAL.LOCAL)                    TYPE(LOCALQ)    CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS)              DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XX11.RAMAN.EQUAL.LOCAL)                        TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUS)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)              DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XX11.REQ.LOCAL)                                TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS)              DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(RAMAN_KATHPLIA_000_11.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE)  TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUS)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS)              DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(DISABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.RAMAN.REMOTE.QUEUE)                   TYPE(QLOCAL)    CLUSTER(STER)       CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)              DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE)                   TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(            )                           CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
```

**Problems:**

1. Certain AIX and Solaris hosts doesn't have "column" command. So can't use "column" universally.
2. Even with usage of column:

   (a) `( )` expands to `(            )`

   (b) More space than necessary is inserted between fields making few rows to fold into next line thus messing up formatting (19 Inch display monitor).

**Questions:**

1. Using awk, Problem 2 re-surfaces (or worse for few lines). Please see below. Can someone suggest a better awk statement ?
2. Also interested to see if Problem 2 can be resolved using "column" command ?

```
$ cat temp.txt | awk '{printf "%-55s  %-15s %-20s %-35s %-15s %-15s %-15s \n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}'
QUEUE(XYZ1.REQ.YAM.ALIAS)                                TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUS)      CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)                  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ4.REPL.YAM)                                     TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYSTER)      CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.YAM)                                      TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCTER)      CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)                  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(NO)    PUT(DISABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ8.REPLY.YAM)                                    TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(             )                                   CLUSQMGR(ABCD)  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.K.LQ)                                     TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)   CLUSQMGR()                          CLUSQT(QLOCAL)  DEFPSIST(NO)    PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.KATHPALIA)                                TYPE(QREMOTE)   CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)   CLUSQMGR(ABCD)                      CLUSQT(QLOCAL)  DEFPSIST(NO)    PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(KATHPLAIA.RAMAN)                                   TYPE(           )                    CLUSTER(                            )               CLUSQMGR(ABCD)  CLUSQT(QLOCAL)
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.EQUAL.LQ)                                 TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)   CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QLOCAL)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ9.RAMAN.EQUAL.LQ)                               TYPE(QL)        CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)   CLUSQMGR(ABCD)                      CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XX10.REPL.EQUAL.ALIAS)                             TYPE(QA)        CLUSTER(YOURC)       CLUSQMGR(ABCD)                      CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(DISABLED)
QUEUE(XX10.KATHPLAIA.EQUAL.LOCAL)                        TYPE(LOCALQ)    CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)   CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XX11.RAMAN.EQUAL.LOCAL)                            TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUS)      CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)                  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XX11.REQ.LOCAL)                                    TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)   CLUSQMGR(ABCD)                      CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(RAMAN_KATHPLIA_000_11.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE)      TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUS)      CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(DISABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.RAMAN.REMOTE.QUEUE)                       TYPE(QLOCAL)    CLUSTER(STER)        CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)                  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE)                       TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(             )                                   CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH) CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)
```

**Field info:**

All fields are bound and don't expand beyond certain length.

```
- Max Width field 1 = 55
- Max Width field 2 = 15
- Max Width field 3 = 20
- Max Width field 4 = 30
- Max Width field 5 = 15
- Max Width field 6 = 15
- Max Width field 7 = 15
```

**Limitation**:

I want to optimize the display for least sized monitor in organisation == 19 Inches

So, I want to minimize the gap between columns to a single space. Possibly, checkered columns (like MS Excel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One easy solution would be to use the `)` as the field separator for `awk`. That gets around both of the issues you mention. However, that also removes the `)` from each line, so you need to add them back when you call `printf`:

```
$ awk -F')' '{printf "%-55s  %-15s %-20s %-35s %-15s %-15s %-15s \n",
                      $1")",$2")",$3")",$4")",$5")",$6")",$7")"}' temp.txt 
QUEUE(XYZ1.REQ.YAM.ALIAS)                                 TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUS)      CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)                  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XYZ4.REPL.YAM)                                      TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYSTER)      CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.YAM)                                       TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCTER)      CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)                  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(NO)    PUT(DISABLED)  
QUEUE(XYZ8.REPLY.YAM)                                     TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER( )           CLUSQMGR(ABCD)                      CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.K.LQ)                                      TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)   CLUSQMGR()                          CLUSQT(QLOCAL)  DEFPSIST(NO)    PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.KATHPALIA)                                 TYPE(QREMOTE)   CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)   CLUSQMGR(ABCD)                      CLUSQT(QLOCAL)  DEFPSIST(NO)    PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(KATHPLAIA.RAMAN)                                    TYPE( )         CLUSTER( )           CLUSQMGR(ABCD)                      CLUSQT(QLOCAL)  DEFPSIST(NO)    PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.EQUAL.LQ)                                  TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)   CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QLOCAL)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XYZ9.RAMAN.EQUAL.LQ)                                TYPE(QL)        CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)   CLUSQMGR(ABCD)                      CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XX10.REPL.EQUAL.ALIAS)                              TYPE(QA)        CLUSTER(YOURC)       CLUSQMGR(ABCD)                      CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(DISABLED)  
QUEUE(XX10.KATHPLAIA.EQUAL.LOCAL)                         TYPE(LOCALQ)    CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)   CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XX11.RAMAN.EQUAL.LOCAL)                             TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUS)      CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)                  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XX11.REQ.LOCAL)                                     TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)   CLUSQMGR(ABCD)                      CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(RAMAN_KATHPLIA_000_11.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE)       TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUS)      CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(DISABLED)  
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.RAMAN.REMOTE.QUEUE)                        TYPE(QLOCAL)    CLUSTER(STER)        CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)                  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE)                        TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER( )           CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)   PUT(ENABLED)
```

I don't understand why you have those extra spaces though. Why not something like this:

```
$ awk -F')' '{printf "%-51s%-15s%-20s%-28s%-15s%-15s%-15s\n",
                      $1")",$2")",$3")",$4")",$5")",$6")",$7")"}' temp.txt 
QUEUE(XYZ1.REQ.YAM.ALIAS)                           TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUS)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)  
QUEUE(XYZ4.REPL.YAM)                                TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYSTER)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)  
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.YAM)                                 TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCTER)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(NO)   PUT(DISABLED) 
QUEUE(XYZ8.REPLY.YAM)                               TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER( )          CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)  
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.K.LQ)                                TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR()                  CLUSQT(QLOCAL) DEFPSIST(NO)   PUT(ENABLED)  
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.KATHPALIA)                           TYPE(QREMOTE)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QLOCAL) DEFPSIST(NO)   PUT(ENABLED)  
QUEUE(KATHPLAIA.RAMAN)                              TYPE( )        CLUSTER( )          CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QLOCAL) DEFPSIST(NO)   PUT(ENABLED)  
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.EQUAL.LQ)                            TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QLOCAL) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)  
QUEUE(XYZ9.RAMAN.EQUAL.LQ)                          TYPE(QL)       CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)  
QUEUE(XX10.REPL.EQUAL.ALIAS)                        TYPE(QA)       CLUSTER(YOURC)      CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(DISABLED) 
QUEUE(XX10.KATHPLAIA.EQUAL.LOCAL)                   TYPE(LOCALQ)   CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)  
QUEUE(XX11.RAMAN.EQUAL.LOCAL)                       TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUS)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)  
QUEUE(XX11.REQ.LOCAL)                               TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)  
QUEUE(RAMAN_KATHPLIA_000_11.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE) TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUS)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(DISABLED) 
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.RAMAN.REMOTE.QUEUE)                  TYPE(QLOCAL)   CLUSTER(STER)       CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)  
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE)                  TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER( )          CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)
```

---

Another approach is to convert all spaces following a `)` to tabs and use tabs as the field separator:

```
$ sed 's/)  */)\t/g' temp.txt | 
    awk -F'\t' '{printf "%-52s%-15s%-20s%-28s%-15s%-15s%-15s\n",
                         $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}'
QUEUE(XYZ1.REQ.YAM.ALIAS)                           TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUS)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XYZ4.REPL.YAM)                                TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYSTER)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.YAM)                                 TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCTER)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(NO)   PUT(DISABLED)  
QUEUE(XYZ8.REPLY.YAM)                               TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER( )          CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.K.LQ)                                TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR()                  CLUSQT(QLOCAL) DEFPSIST(NO)   PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.KATHPALIA)                           TYPE(QREMOTE)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QLOCAL) DEFPSIST(NO)   PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(KATHPLAIA.RAMAN)                              TYPE( )        CLUSTER( )          CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QLOCAL) DEFPSIST(NO)   PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.EQUAL.LQ)                            TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QLOCAL) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XYZ9.RAMAN.EQUAL.LQ)                          TYPE(QL)       CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XX10.REPL.EQUAL.ALIAS)                        TYPE(QA)       CLUSTER(YOURC)      CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(DISABLED)  
QUEUE(XX10.KATHPLAIA.EQUAL.LOCAL)                   TYPE(LOCALQ)   CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XX11.RAMAN.EQUAL.LOCAL)                       TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUS)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XX11.REQ.LOCAL)                               TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(RAMAN_KATHPLIA_000_11.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE) TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER(MYCLUS)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(DISABLED)  
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.RAMAN.REMOTE.QUEUE)                  TYPE(QLOCAL)   CLUSTER(STER)       CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)   
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE)                  TYPE(QCLUSTER) CLUSTER( )          CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS) DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)
```

Comment: Thanks for a simple solution. I specifically like "another approach" where you've converted all spaces following a ) to tab and use that tab as a field separator.
This has given me more ideas in other areas to implement. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding your other question around "extra spaces"; I gave Max possible length to which a field can expand should an entry arrives requiring Max field. I should have adjusted my example to reflect that.

Answer (score 13):

I would just replace the troublesome `( )` before processing:

```
sed 's/( )/()/g' temp.txt | awk '{printf "%-55s  %-15s %-20s %-35s %-15s %-15s %-15s \n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}'
```

If the number of spaces varies, use

```
sed 's/( \+)/()/g'
```

instead.

Comment: Although gaps in ( ) are absent in temp.txt but introduced by awk statement. I inserted sed at the end and quickly ran into another problem. Gaps introduced by awk are variable in length. This temp.txt is essentially an app generated data in real time that I would be feeding to awk; and I wouldn't know how many space variation in gap exists. :(

Comment: Your initial `cat temp.txt` shows the spaces between the brackets.

Comment: Is it OK if all "()" pairs are replaced with "( )" in the final output? In the input, there's a mixture of "()" and "( )". The idea behind removing the space before running AWK is so that it isn't taken into account when splitting the line into fields, which should then allow consistent output (without the huge gaps between brackets).

Comment: As space is introduced by awk,I didn't try 1st option:

`sed 's/( )/()/g' temp.txt | awk '{printf "%-55s  %-15s %-20s %-35s %-15s %-15s %-15s \n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}'`  - Works

`sed 's/( +)/()/g' temp.txt | awk '{printf "%-55s  %-15s %-20s %-35s %-15s %-15s %-15s \n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}'`  - Does not work

`cat temp.txt | awk '{printf "%-55s  %-15s %-20s %-35s %-15s %-15s %-15s \n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' | sed 's/( +)/()/g'`  - Does not work

`cat temp.txt | awk '{printf "%-55s  %-15s %-20s %-35s %-15s %-15s %-15s \n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' | sed 's/( )/()/g'`  - Does not work

Comment: Sorry for bad formatted response, I'm not sure how to fix response above.

Comment: You could eliminate use of `sed` by performing the substitution within `awk`, using `awk`'s builtin `gsub` function.

Comment: @user1404316 but then you’d have to reparse the line (since we’re splitting on spaces), so the `sed` solution is simpler...

Answer (score 12):

The GNU version of `awk` supports (undocumented and frequently unnoticed) dealing with fixed length columns out of the box. Use the `FIELDWIDTHS` variable to specify the length of each field, then pick the fields with positional variables as usual.

For example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FIELDWIDTHS="16 12 12 12 1"}{print $1 $2 $3 $4 $5}' cars.dat
```

Another way:

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="16 12 12 12 1" '{print $1 $2 $3 $4 $5}' cars.dat
```

If you want to use external variables you can use:

```
FIELDS="10 1 3 3 15 15 15 15 22 8 100 30 20 2 1 10 10 3"
cat file | awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="${FIELDS}" '{print $1,$2,$3}'
```

It saved me lots of time.

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 3):

You could replace `( )` with something like `+++`, pass it to `column -t` and substitute `+++` back:

```
$ sed 's/( )\{1,\}/+++/g' temp.txt | column -t | sed 's/+++/\( \)/g' 
QUEUE(XYZ1.REQ.YAM.ALIAS)                            TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUS)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ4.REPL.YAM)                                 TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYSTER)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.YAM)                                  TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCTER)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(NO)   PUT(DISABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ8.REPLY.YAM)                                TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER( )          CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.K.LQ)                                 TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR()                  CLUSQT(QLOCAL)  DEFPSIST(NO)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(KK.RAMAN.KATHPALIA)                            TYPE(QREMOTE)   CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QLOCAL)  DEFPSIST(NO)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(KATHPLAIA.RAMAN)                               TYPE( )         CLUSTER( )          CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QLOCAL)  DEFPSIST(NO)   PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ8.REQ.EQUAL.LQ)                             TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QLOCAL)  DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ9.RAMAN.EQUAL.LQ)                           TYPE(QL)        CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XX10.REPL.EQUAL.ALIAS)                         TYPE(QA)        CLUSTER(YOURC)      CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(DISABLED)
QUEUE(XX10.KATHPLAIA.EQUAL.LOCAL)                    TYPE(LOCALQ)    CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XX11.RAMAN.EQUAL.LOCAL)                        TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUS)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XX11.REQ.LOCAL)                                TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUSTER)  CLUSQMGR(ABCD)              CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(RAMAN_KATHPLIA_000_11.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE)  TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER(MYCLUS)     CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(DISABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.RAMAN.REMOTE.QUEUE)                   TYPE(QLOCAL)    CLUSTER(STER)       CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAH)          CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)
QUEUE(XYZ2.REQ.EQUAL.REMOTE.QUEUE)                   TYPE(QCLUSTER)  CLUSTER( )          CLUSQMGR(BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH)  CLUSQT(QALIAS)  DEFPSIST(YES)  PUT(ENABLED)
```

This doesn't work for variable with whitespace if you want to keep the exact spacing between `( )`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That's a good trick . 

Together with @Stephen Kitt and your answer, I can now use awk OR  column

This forum is Godsend.

Answer (score 3):

## Method 1: tbl

Assuming GNU sed. Sed generates the `tbl` commands on the fly and then `tbl` is run to generate the desired output.

```
sed -e '
   1i\
.TS\
tab( );

   1{
      h;s/(\s\+)/(,)/g;
      s/\s\+$//;s/^\s\+//;s/\s\+/ /g;
      s/\S\+//g
      s/$/ /;s/ /l&/g;s/.$/./
      G;b
   }
   s/(\s\+)/(,)/g
   $a\
.TE
' | tbl - | nroff -Tascii -ms | sed '/./!d; s/(,)/( )/g'
```

### Explanation

The sed portion is needlessly complex in our case. I wrote to make it not be dependent upon how many columns are in the data & looking at the data in hand to come up with the tbl syntax. Since in our case we are sure there are exactly 7 columns, the sed code could have been simply be written more simply (which is what the sed logic actually was generating essentially, those 7 space separated ells and a trailing dot):

```
sed -e '
   1i\
.TS\
tab( );\
l l l l l l l.
   s/(\s\+)/(,)/g
   $a\
.TE
'
```

The essential boilerplate of the tbl boils down to the following:

1. Mandatory .TS for the start of table
2. data delimiters using    tab(delim_char);
3. columnar publishing: l -> left-justified, r-> right justified, c->center-justified, & n-numeric col. Their number must match the data cols.
4. Mandatory .TE for the end of table
5. pass on the o/p of tbl to nroff and that's all there's to this utility.

## Method 2: Perl

This method determines the maximum widths per field and then using this info generates the printf format specifier dynamically. This method will give the shortest spacing.

```
perl -lne '
   tr/\t/ /;
   s/\((\s+)\)/"(" . "+" x length($1) . ")"/eg;
   ($a, @F) = (-1, split);
   s/\((\++)\)/"(" . " " x length($1) . ")"/eg for @F;
   push @A, [@F];
   $a++, length > $maxW[$a] and $maxW[$a] = length for @F;
   END {
      my $fmt = join $", map { "%-${_}s" } @maxW;
      print sprintf $fmt, @$_ for @A;
   }
' temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the same file twice. In the first pass, calculate the maximum width feild. Even a different number of fields is allowed on each line:

```
awk -F') ' '
BEGIN   {ARGV[2]=ARGV[1]; ARGC+=1}
NR==FNR {for(;--NF;){
                l=length($NF)
                if(A[NF]<l)A[NF]=l}
                next
        }
        {for(i=1; i<NF; i++)
                printf("%-*s", A[i]+2, $i FS)
                print $NF
        }
' file
```

Instead of the `BEGIN` section, you can use a repeated file name:
`file file` or `file{,}`